# what is the advantage of declaring instance variable of collection (list, map) as final in java

Tags: java, collections, final

What is the point of declaring instance variable as final

```
final List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Comment: It makes it clear that you don't want or intend to change the value of the variable.

Comment: this implies that we are trying to make the reference as immutable i.e reference value cannot be changed

Comment: It guarantees visibility of the assigned value to other threads.

Comment: @Louis this is a bad dupe. OP isn't asking about local variables and method parameters. It's just a dupe of some other question, though.

Comment: @greenHorn: Yes, exactly.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Thanks for the clarification.